# How to resize all controls on a form at run-time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resize, controls

I have a Windows form which contains a grid of PictureBox controls.  I want to be able to resize the entire form at runtime and have all of these PictureBox controls dynamically resize (scale) proportionally to accommodate the form's new size.  The goal is to avoid having to make separate resource files that would essentially make use of the same .cs file just because I want different sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying using a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) control with all rows and columns in percent mode.

```
new Form {
    Controls = {
        new TableLayoutPanel {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            ColumnCount = 2,
            Controls = {
                new Button {Text = "0,0", Dock = DockStyle.Fill},
                new Button {Text = "1,0", Dock = DockStyle.Fill},
                new Button {Text = "0,1", Dock = DockStyle.Fill},
                new Button {Text = "1,1", Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
            },
            RowStyles = {
                new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent) {Height = 1},
                new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent) {Height = 1}
            },
            ColumnStyles = {
                new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent) {Width = 1},
                new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent) {Width = 1}
            }
        }
    }
}.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: awesome, man!  You rock!  Do you know if TableLayoutPanel can be nested?  I need to make a pretty complex form where one "cell" has multiple smaller cells while the others are not so complex.  Thanks again!

Comment: I was able to nest them without any problem.  The question I have now is if it is possible to have .NET auto scale fonts for child controls or if the developer has to manually perform this?